# Know of any open source zend framework calendar?

Tags: php, zend-framework, calendar

I'm trying to find an open source PHP calendar that will play nicely with my zend framework application. Ideally, I should be able to display the events on the public site, and add/edit/delete events in the admin section.

Anything that would keep me from re-inventing the wheel so I can get a head start would be great.

**Update:** At the moment, I have embedded a google calendar that I can update from the Google Calendar site, but I am still looking for something that has been done using the Zend Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a javascript calendar that allows you to feed it data and it will do the rest.  I've looked into http://www.bytecyclist.com/projects/jmonthcalendar/ in the past, and it seems to be sufficient.

Basically, feed your data to your view, or to a helper you create, and jmonthcalendar will fill the calendar.  I believe it also supports clicking on the date which triggers a function you can define to get/send data to a controller, etc.  It has a lot of other features, but I'll let you read those on your own at that url.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo has a calendar widget for editing http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dijit.form.DateTextBox

Creating a calendar controller is pretty easy: only a couple of hours work.

Sometimes it can take several hours to get a third party calendar widget integrated into your app. I've messed around with this sort of things a few times and regretted it. Most of the time, for simple stuff like this, it is easier to quickly roll your own rather than spend 2 hours hunting for a third party one, a few hours getting it installed and working, another hour figuring out some mysterious bug etc etc....

Comment: I know what you mean. I could have written my own in the time I spent looking for a third party solution