# Zend Framework Project - Calendar: Need web calendar with events (like google calendar) for every user separately

Tags: php, zend-framework, calendar

I doing multi users website (it should works for more than 100,000 users) with Zend Framework.

I need to create event calendar like google calendar (If it was possible to use google calendar i will do it- please tell me).

I have to do that from zero or exist some good Calendar that will work well with Zend?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some calendars proposals on ZF, e.g. this [Zend_Calendar proposal](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Calendar+-+Kyle+Spraggs). You can easily extend it with Google Calendar as a data provider.

Take a look at alternative to Google Calendar, written in jQuery: [wdCalendar](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins/) as well.

Comment: How can I integrate wdCalendar (Its not looks MVC) in Zend Project?

Answer (score 4):

Check out full calendar by Arshaw.

This is a jQuery plugin that provides a full-sized, drag & drop calendar just like google calendar. one can also customize it easily.

[Full Calenadar Link](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with Google Calendar, have a look at [`Zend_Gdata`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.introduction.html):

> Google Data APIs provide programmatic interface to some of Google's online services. The Google data Protocol is based upon the » Atom Publishing Protocol and allows client applications to retrieve data matching queries, post data, update data and delete data using standard HTTP and the Atom syndication formation. The Zend_Gdata  component is a PHP 5 interface for accessing Google Data from PHP. The Zend_Gdata component also supports accessing other services implementing the Atom Publishing Protocol.

Specifically the chapter on [Using Google Calendar](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html):

> You can use the Zend_Gdata_Calendar  class to view, create, update, and delete events in the online Google Calendar service.

Also see http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/ for more information about Google Data API.

---

Also see the answers to these questions:

- [Know of any open source Zend Framework calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134954/know-of-any-open-source-zend-framework-calendar)
- [Which PHP calendar will suit my needs? Or build my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990678/which-php-calendar-will-suit-my-needs-or-build-my-own)
- [Calendar using Javascript/ PHP/ mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805806/calendar-using-javascript-php-mysql)

Comment: Ok, but i will have to open for each website user separate google account.My calendar should be not global.

Comment: @Yosef well, then why do you ask how to do it with Google Calendar :)

Comment: 1. like google calendar 

or 

2. google calendar for each user - I know that is impossible but maybe i wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use Google Calendar Api. You would need to create a calendar for each user using [Calendar Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#CreatingCalendars). And when a user is logged show him his calendar in a google calendar embed. I didn't try that, but I will try tomorrow. If it is not posible I will let you know.